# Failed Query nameOf in Pallet Interactor

Tags: substrate, pallet

I've added Nicks pallet as in [Add a Pallet to Your Runtime](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/add-a-pallet/) tutorial.

The pallet successfully added and in the front-end it can interact with the Pallet Interactor submitting Exterinsic setName. But it's failed when I query the nameOf from Nicks pallet for the given account (Alice).

Where should I look at what went wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Code link?
And what do you mean failed? If there's a screenshot that would be better.

Comment: Code link https://github.com/SHA888/substrate-tutorial-node/blob/master/runtime/src/lib.rs

The query response: None

Comment: Does your extrinsic end up in a block? try using the https://polkadot.js.org/apps/ UI to issue these and watch the `Explorer` tab (keep it open) to look at events. You should see no errors, and the state set.

Comment: please also add screen shots and more details to your question. It gives no information about what exactly happened to help you.